# Gaussian Approximation of an intractable distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

I am currently encountering this problem:

I have an intractable distribution and I want to minimize the KL divergence of this distribution and a multivariate gaussian distribution. So we just need to find out the precision matrix.

The distribution is so complicated that it is not really possible to calculate the gradient or Hessian of the distribution function. All we can to is to evaluate the distribution function.

Is there any algorithm that actually solves such a problem or any suggestions on this? Thank you very much!

Comment: what is precision matrix. can you give more details about your problem?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören precision matrix is just the inverse of covariance  matrix or simply p=c*exp(X_t*K*X) if K is the precision matrix.

Comment: what about using a monte carlo type approach?

Comment: Do you mean KL distance? Relative to what distribution? Typically, the MLE minimizes the KL distance between a given distribution family and the true distribution. Are you trying to get the MLEs of the precision matrix for a multivariate gaussian approximation to your actual distribution?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören it is almost impossible to draw sample from the original distribution so I assume MC method does not work?

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 yes, but is it possible to do that? KL divergence has got an integration form, do you have any examples? Thank you very much!

Comment: Heres a general reference on how this works: http://nowak.ece.wisc.edu/SLT09/lecture13.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the distribution function, you can generate samples from it using Markov Chain Monte Carlo (not Classical Monte Carlo). In MCMC (as it is termed) you only need the distribution function. In particular, I think the [Metropolis-Hastings MCMC algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm) will work well for you. You can use this algorithm to approximate the mean vector and covariance matrix of your data. If you are not familiar with this technique, I suggest you consult with someone with experience in computational statsistics, as MCMC is much trickier to work with than standard Monte Carlo due to the autocorrelation in the generated sequence of random values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Eupraxis1981 the problem with my sample is it is not possible to draw samples nor to implement MCMC due to causality issue(observed variables are the children of hidden variables.)

Comment: @Junting Zhu I thought you said you could calculate the value of the distribution function? If you can do that then MCMC methods are applicable... Note that MCMC is different from classical MC